# Subtract number from array

Tags: c#, arrays, subtraction

I have a program that uses an array that looks like this:

1,2,3,4,5

I have a number '10' and what I want to do is to subtract that number from the array.

It's difficult to explain, but I am using multiple elements of the array in that subtraction.
This would have to happen :

```
   10 - 5 = 5 (array looks now like this => 1,2,3,4)
   5  - 4 = 1 (array looks now like this => 1,2,3)
   3  - 1 = 2 (array looks now like this => 1,2,2)
```

So as a summary:

this : 1,2,3,4,5 minus 10 would give me 1,2,2

But how do I do this?
The programming language is C#

EDIT :

input =

1 . An array with 5 integers as elements : 1, 2 ,3 ,4 and 5
 2 . A number 10 (integer)

process =

1. 10 is subtracted from the last value and then the resulting number is subtracted from the next element of the array until there is nothing left of '10'.

output =

instead of 1,2,3,4,5 => 1,2,2
(comma's separate the elements in the array)

Comment: I don't understand the question :-s and cant see why the arrays == what they do after the operation

Comment: You should loop from the last index to the first and remove/change each value

Comment: so in order to loop from the last index,... should i use a for loop like this : for(int i==5;i=0;i--){;} ?

Comment: Do you mean that there is one array with 10 elements. And when 5 is subtracted it will be having only values less then the result obtained?

Comment: yes but in the question i use ',' to separate the different values in the array and 10 is an integer

Comment: Can you please mention all the values of the array and actual result? So that the question can become more understandable.

Comment: ok - see the question ; i edited it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
public static int[] Subtract(int[] array, int value) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, array))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

  if (value < 0) 
    return Addition(array, -value);

  int s = 0;

  int index = 0;
  int delta = 0;

  for (int i = array.GetLength(0) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    s += array[i];

    if (s > value) {
      index = i;
      delta = s - value;

      break;
    }
  }

  // Too big a value is subtracted, let's return an empty array
  if ((index <= 0) && (delta <= 0)) // <- (delta <= 0) to prevent [x, ... z, 0] answers
    return new int[0];

  int[] result = new int[index + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    result[i] = array[i];

  result[index] = delta;

  return result;
}

// Maximum possible electrons within orbital; 0 - s1, 1 - s1, 2 - p1, 3 - s2 etc.
// Double arithmetic progression's here (main quantum number - level, orbital quantum number - s, p, d...)
private static int MaxElectronsCount(int value) {
  Double n = (-1 + Math.Sqrt(1 + 8.0 * (value + 1))) / 2;

  int group = (int)(n + 1.0 - 1.0e-8); // <- round up to high limit
  int shift = group - (group * (group + 1) / 2 - value);

  return 2 + shift * 4;
}

// Electrons addition 
public static int[] Addition(int[] array, int value) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, array))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

  if (value < 0)
    return Subtraction(array, -value);

  List<int> result = new List<int>();

  for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); ++i)
    result.Add(array[i]);

  int level = 0;

  while (value > 0) {
    if (result.Count <= level)
      result.Add(0);

    int max = MaxElectronsCount(level);
    int delta = max - result[level];

    if (delta > value)
      delta = value;

    if (delta > 0) {
      result[level] = result[level] + delta;
      value -= delta;
    }

    level += 1;
  }

  return result.ToArray();
}
....  

int[] test1 = Subtract(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 1); // <- [1, 2, 3, 4, 4] 
int[] test2 = Subtract(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 5); // <- [1, 2, 3, 4] 
int[] test3 = Subtract(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 6); // <- [1, 2, 3, 3] 
int[] test4 = Subtract(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 10); // <- [1, 2, 2]
int[] test5 = Subtract(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 1000); // <- [] 
int[] test6 = Subtract(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, -1); // <- [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
int[] test7 = Subtract(new int[] { 2, 2 }, 2); // <- [2]

int[] test8 = Addition(new int[] {2, 1}, 16); // <- [2, 2, 6, 2, 6, 1]
```

Comment: ok - I tried it; it works ok but just when i have an array ({2,2}) then it returns 0 when I subtract '2'. How can I fix this?

Comment: and could you also please give an example for how to add up to an array (instead of subtract)?

Comment: Addition unlike subtraction, IMHO, could be very simple (see my edit), in one word Addition(array, value) = Subtraction(array, -value);

Comment: ok - and what would I do in case there are certain rules for adding up (I'm trying to simulate addition of electrons to an electronconfiguration) because I don't want to use too much if/else statements

Comment: for example the first element can maximally contain 2 values, 2nd= 2,3rd = 6,4th = 2;5th = 6;..... (s,p,d,f,..orbitals)

Comment: Could you specify the rules and regulations explicitly? Just in form "n-th item of the array (n is zero based) could be at most f(n)". What is f(n)?

Comment: ok - here are the vars with the set values for each type : s=2 p=6 d=10 f=14 and the order in the array is : sspspdspdfspdfspdfs

Comment: and a d-orbital is only filled when a s orbital from a higher level is filled and a f-orbital is only filled when a s and (one element in d) from 2 higher levels are filled...

Comment: Well, there's no formula f(n) provided as I asked; OK I've done it for you - MaxElectronsCount - (spent a year in Electrochemistry lab). See my edit. FYI: there're some exceptions of the rule s2p..(Cr, e.g.) where S level has 1 electron only, while P levels is not empty.

Comment: that is absolutely great! :) also thank you for mentioning the exceptions with Chromium/... but they aren't applicable in this situation. thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please rewrite the code in order that it adds first to a 4s and then to a 3d? (also : first 6s, then 3f and onwards) Because I'm using the method 'filling up' using the periodic table (where d and f blocks come higher, but have lower energy levels)

Comment: i'm sorry if I ask you too much; but could you  at least just give me an idea on how I could do this faster (without/with less using if statements?

Comment: State the problem formally (from the very beginning to the very end). Incremental design here is a way to nowhere. Think over on what do you want to have: just two functions on array or, say, a class "ElectronConfiguration"? In the last particular problem the simplest solution is to encode yet another function (like MaxElectronsCount which I did) that returns level to be filled next.

Comment: ok : I've changed the order of filling up the electrons (now it is : [ sspspsdpsdps(d^1)f(d continues filling up to 10)ps(d^1)f(d continues filling up)p ] because I need the addition of electrons to fill up according to the periodic table's orbital blocks... also there is an exception : where I wrote (d^1) only 1 electron can be added to the d-orbital (eg. Lanthanum) and then it continues to add up electrons on a f-orbital. (continues in next comment...)

Comment: When the f-orbital is full, it will continue filling up that incomplete d-orbital and then it will continue normally with filling up the next p-orbital,... (this also happens a second time). There would have to be 2 functions : one that can add up electrons and one that subtracts the electrons. (very important is again following the exceptions that I stated earlier).

Comment: The functions wouldn't have to be in a class.

Comment: do please help me, I'm not a trained professional and when I try to write code for complex operations, the lists of code are very long(using loops and if statements) could you please create those two functions for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood you but try this:

```
private void SubstractNumberFromArray(List<int> array, int number)
{
    //array.Sort();
    for (int i = array.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int toSubstract = Math.Min(number, array[i]);
        array[i] -= toSubstract;
        if (array[i] == 0)
            array.RemoveAt(i);
        number -= toSubstract;

        if (number == 0)
            break;
    }

    if (number != 0)
        throw new Exception("Can't substract!");

}
```